# Dataframe not displaying correct schema for a folder path

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some Snappy compressed Parquet files in S3 bucket and using Pyspark, I am trying to read the data of the files and print its schema. But when I am reading from the folder path, the schema is different than the schema of individual files.

Schema of Folder path:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket_name/rds-aurora/core/")
df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- rid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- revision: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- type: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- content_dataType: long (nullable = true)
```

Schema when reading individual file:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket_name/rds-aurora/core/part-00008-c000.snappy.parquet")
df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- rid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- revision: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- type: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- content_dataType: long (nullable = true)
 |-- content_definitionName: string (nullable = true)
```

Column **content_definitionName** is missing from the schema of the folder path. Any help would be appreciated to find out why/how can I get the Folder schema same as individual file schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you have some parquet files that have different schemas in there. See [Parquet schema merging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging):

> Like Protocol Buffer, Avro, and Thrift, Parquet also supports schema
> evolution. Users can start with a simple schema, and gradually add
> more columns to the schema as needed. In this way, users may end up
> with multiple Parquet files with different but mutually compatible
> schemas. The Parquet data source is now able to automatically detect
> this case and merge schemas of all these files.
>
> [...] we turned it off by default starting from 1.5.0. You may enable
> it by
>
> 1. setting data source option `mergeSchema` to true when reading Parquet files (as shown in the examples below), or
> 2. setting the global SQL option `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` to true.

Try adding option `mergeSchema` when you read from the folder path:

```
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("s3://bucket_name/rds-aurora/core/")
```